# as3 var not listening to x--

Tags: actionscript-3, math, var

So Ive got this code:

```
function speedUp():void
    {
        trace ("speed", playerSpeed);
        //checks if any boosts are on
        if (boostCheck == false) {j = playerSpeed}
        //making speed limit
        if (playerSpeed < speedLimit)
        {
            playerSpeed ++;
        }

        //increasing speed limit
        if (speedLimitInc == 100)
        {
            speedLimit++;
            speedLimitInc = 1;
        }
        trace ("______________j", j);
        speedLimitInc ++;
        if (boostCheck == true)
        {
            for (var i:int = boost.length-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                var tempBoostN:int = boost[i];
                trace ("__________tempBoostN", tempBoostN);
                if (tempBoostN >= 0)
                {boostCheck = true; colBoolean = false; tempBoostN--;}
                else 
                {
                    boostCheck = false;
                    player.y = player.height + 30;
                    colBoolean = true;
                }
                if (playerSpeed >= j)
                {
                    if (tempBoostN >= 150)
                    {
                        playerSpeed = playerSpeed -1;

                    } else if (tempBoostN <= 150 && tempBoostN >= 30) {
                        playerSpeed = playerSpeed - 2;
                    }
                    tempBoostN--;
                }
            }
        }
         }
```

Im getting a problem with `tempBoostN` variable, more to point, its not listening to commands. When the var is, say, 200 (its defined as an int) and I do `tempBoostN--` like you see in code, it just stays 200.

I have tried defining the var as a Number as etc.. but it stays the same.
I have also checked that the 200 is actually a Number not a string (if var is int the it cant hold a string, right?) by doing `trace(temBoostN - 1);` and that worked.

CODE EXPLANATION:
Function handles playerSpeed, first it does usual behaviour (increasing the speed and stuff).
After that (the part where I get the problem) checks for speed boosts activated and for each it decreases the speed back to normal speed when the boost is deactivated. var j holds playerSpeed without any boosts and is used to check if boosts ran out.

All the vars in the code are defined and working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you actually want to do is get the decrement reflected in boost[i]. What is the type of 'boost[i]'. I believe it's `int` and that's why changing tempBoostN isn't changing boost[i]. There are 2 ways around it:

(1) You put `Number` in boost[i], so tempBoostN = boost[i] is a assignment by reference as against a value copy being done in case of `int`

(2) re-assign boost[i] = tempBoostN at the end of loop.

Comment: Thanks, I made tempBoostN a Number instead of int, re-assigned the array and now it works. Thanks again!

Comment: btw, you don't need to change type if you are re-assigning... if you make both boost[i] and tempBoostN a Number, then re-assignment shouldn't be required.